# How to include your own javascript file in Connections?

Tags: ibm-connections

I try include multiple javascript files in IBM Connections like jQuery or other library.

i find this documentation : http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.0/doc/en_us/ic4_p4.html#t_customize_extend_js

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please give more details than "it doesn't work.". What did you try? What *did* happen? Were there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Put e.g. the following line into the footer.jsp in your customization directory.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://<pathtolib>/jquery.js"></script>
```

Be sure to turn on CONNECTIONS_CUSTOMIZATION_DEBUG (WebSphere variable), otherwise you have to restart your AS everytime you make a change.

Take a look in the SystemOut.log for footer.jsp if it is loaded again when you change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only distribute Dojo (pre-AMD) modules with the OSGi bundle approach outlined in the [product documentation](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.0/doc/en_us/ic4_p4.html#t_customize_extend_js).

To include third party libraries, you must include a `<script>` tag in the customizable `header.jsp` or `footer.jsp`. To achieve best front-end performance it's best to include scripts at the bottom of the page, therefore `footer.jsp` is the right location.